# AWS dynamodb endpoints is not correct

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, sails.js

I am using `sails js` (latest version 1.0) with DynamoDB (I have installed Sails js framework at my local machine) but when  have tried to reading the records from `aws dynamodb` then its giving error. I have tried below cases and every time getting different errors.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:1337"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var table = "SMSGateway_User";
var email = 'yoursptc@gmail.com';

var params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key:{
        "userEmail": email
    }
};

docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

**Error which I am getting:**

> Unable to read item. Error JSON: {   "message": "Missing credentials
>   in config",   "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",   "code": "CredentialsError",
>   "syscall": "connect",   "address": "169.254.169.254",   "port": 80,
>   "time": "2018-10-05T05:05:26.002Z",   "originalError": {
>       "message": "Could not load credentials from any providers",
>       "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
>       "code": "CredentialsError",
>       "syscall": "connect",
>       "address": "169.254.169.254",
>       "port": 80,
>       "time": "2018-10-05T05:05:26.001Z",
>       "originalError": {
>         "errno": "ETIMEDOUT",
>         "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
>         "syscall": "connect",
>         "address": "169.254.169.254",
>         "port": 80,
>         "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 169.254.169.254:80"
>       }   } }

**When I changed and add below code for config:**

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:1337"
});
```

Then getting below error:

> Unable to read item. Error JSON: {   "message": "Not Found",   "code":
>   "UnknownError",   "statusCode": 404,   "time":
>   "2018-10-05T06:08:28.707Z",   "retryable": false,   "retryDelay":
>   47.4917958614573 }

**When I change end point and put ARN**

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  endpoint: "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:420344081058:table/SMSGateway_User"
});
```

**Error is:**

> Unable to read item. Error JSON: {   "message": "Inaccessible host:
>   `arn'. This service may not be available in the`ap-southeast-2'
>   region.",   "code": "UnknownEndpoint",   "region": "ap-southeast-2",
>   "hostname": "arn",   "retryable": true,   "originalError": {
>       "message": "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND arn arn:443",
>       "errno": "ENOTFOUND",
>       "code": "NetworkingError",
>       "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
>       "hostname": "arn",
>       "host": "arn",
>       "port": 443,
>       "region": "ap-southeast-2",
>       "retryable": true,
>       "time": "2018-10-05T06:17:21.352Z"   },   "time": "2018-10-05T06:17:21.352Z" }

Can anyone tell me which one is correct end point to read,create,update and delete data in dynamoDB.

I am following this reference: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.02

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of research I have got the solution why it was not working

```
   var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
   //AWS.config.loadFromPath('details.json');
   AWS.config.update({
     accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
     region: "XXXXXXXXX",
   });

   var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

/* Get single item */

   var table = "TABLE NAME";
   var msgId = 'PRIMARY KEY VALUE';
   var params = {
       TableName: table,
       Key:{
           'MsgId': msgId
       }
   };

   docClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       }
   });
```

**To fetch all records of table just use the scan function like below**

```
   var table = "PadmanStopsTest";
   var params = {
       TableName: table,
   };
   docClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
           console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       }
   });
```

No end points required just need to pass the `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` and `region`. I was passing email in params so here we need to pass the primary key value of table.

I have passed and its working fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, docs of AWS are too confusing!!!